# Getting no results when using jQuery to call php

Tags: php, jquery

Below is the code I'm using to call my validate script. The purpose is to accept input from the user and send it to validate.php to check if what they have entered matches our records and return either a true or false value. I'm getting no response. I've tried `<?php echo "Result" ?>` just to see if a different value would work. Both are in the same domain so I don't believe it's an issue with origin of both files.

```
$.get(
        "validate.php",
        {AN : AccNo, SC : SortCode},
        function(data) {
           alert('page content: ' + data);
        }
    );
```

Update: I've had a look in the network tab as suggested in the debugger and nothing showed and the it said it was out of memory. I'm not too sure why as it isn't a large request.

Comment: Your JS code looks fine. Have you debugged this at all by checking the request is sent and is successful? You can do that in the 'network' tab of the console

Comment: Once check if its going to validate.php if not check the file location whether its in same folder or root folder and give path as per that